# React says it cannot find file specified, I have checked directory and name and all seem to be fine

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

`enter code here`

```js
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchPosts, fetchUsers }
)(PostList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

> ./src/components/App.js
>   Cannot find file: 'Postlist.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\components\PostList.js'.

Instead of using conventional export before class name I exported it through the connect function of react-redux. I am new to redux and still don't completely understand how the connect function works.

```
> import React from "react";
import PostList from "./PostList";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <PostList />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Your error is not related to the code you post. Can you post specifically all import statements?

Answer (score 1):

Although your code is incomplete, it seems a typo: you are importing Postlist (with lowercase "l") and exporting PostList (with uppercase "L"). You need to import PostList with uppercase in App.js.

Comment: The L was already uppercase and that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: The error message clearly show the typo: Cannot find file: 'Postlist.js'. Are you still  facing the same error?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late reply, but I managed to resolve the problem. The problem was that I was hosting it on Heroku and I hadn't done `git add .` or `git add .\src\components\PostList.js` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

import PostList from './PostList';

1) As I can see that both App.js and PostList.js are in the same folder user can 
   use the above line of code will work fine.
2) You should Import the component as you have exported. ( Import / export case sensitive)

Comment: I have imported the PostList in App.js and made sure it's case sensitive.

Comment: can you share me your PostList.js file.